# Why does overshoot_interpolator not work?

Tags: android, animation

**RESOLVED**
If I write animation xml like below, overshoot_interpolator does not work.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true"
 android:fillBefore="true">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="20%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>
<!-- other code -->
</set>
```

If I put android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator" into set, it will work.But the problem is that other animation will also has this interpolator.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true"
 android:fillBefore="true"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="20%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>

<!-- other code -->
</set>
```

Comment: Here is the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311290/android-is-it-possible-to-use-concurrent-interpolators

Answer (score 1):

Interpolars are shared within `<set>`. To use different interpolars, specify `android:shareInterpolator="false"` to the `<set>`.